# Easier way to find (visual) position of QModelIndex in QTreeView

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, qtreeview, qmodelindex

I'm interested in calculating the physical position of a node in `QTreeView` and can't find a way to do this (other than calculating it myself, which is cumbersome and error prone given the robustness of `QTreeView`).

Is there a standard way of finding the draw position of data associated with a `QModelIndex` (something similar to the way `indexAt()` maps a position to a `QModelIndex`)?

Comment: No need to apologize---just answer your own question and accept the answer. That's encouraged behavior on Stack Overflow. Will even earn you the "self-learner" badge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a method in `QAbstractItemView` that does exactly what I needed:

The signature is:

```
virtual QRect visualRect ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
```