# Easier way to find visible row of a QModelIndex in a QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qmodelindex

Is there a way to get "visual row" of a given `QModelIndex`?

Let's say we have a tree with some nodes expanded and some not. For example, take a partially expanded tree and click on a last item:

```
item1    # (visual) row 1
  item2  # 2
  item5  # 3
item7    # 4
  item8  # 5 <-- click here
```

I want to know that item I clicked is in the 5th row, programmatically. `QModelIndex`'s rows and columns are not helpful, as there is hierarchy here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to find (visual) position of QModelIndex in QTreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739643/easier-way-to-find-visual-position-of-qmodelindex-in-qtreeview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of your rows have the same height, you can compute the visual row like this:

```
int visual_row(const QTreeView *tv, const QModelIndex &mi)
{
    const QRect visualRect = tv->visualRect(mi);
    if (visualRect.isValid())
        return visualRect.y() / visualRect.height();
    else
        return -1; // invisible
}
```

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: yes, that's what I said in the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, agree. I'm blind. Voted up.